# Access user profile information for onRender template using iron-router

Tags: jquery, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to access user data in code on the client for my user profile pages onRendered.

I have this in my client:

```
 Template.profile.onRendered(function () {
      $('#qrblock').qrcode({text: <I want to show user's qrUrl here>});
    });
```

Here is the user schema when a user is created:

```
Accounts.createUser({
    username: username,
    emails: [
      { address: email, verified: false }
    ],
    password: password,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    profile:{
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
    },
    qrUrl: 'test.meteor.com/@' + username
  },
...
...
...
```

Here is my template:

```
<template name="profile">
<div class="container-fluid">
    Username:   {{username}}<br />
    {{#with profile}}
        Profile name: {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    {{/with}}
    <div id="qrblock"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

Here's my router and controller:

```
Router.route('/@:username', {
  name: 'profile',
  controller: 'ProfileController'
});

ProfileController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'profile',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('userProfile', this.params.username);
  },
  data: function() {
    var username = Router.current().params.username;
    return Meteor.users.findOne({
      username: username
    });
  }
})
```

I'm not very great with the meteor routing stuff so that's confusing me when it comes to accessing user data for a specific profile page.  I hope what I'm trying to do is even possible.

How do I use user data in my profile Template onRendered function?

Comment: I've just fixed it!  My problem was with the user schema, it doesn't seem to like me just making a qrUrl outside the profile bracket. I added it in there and it worked perfectly.  Thank you for the this.data.qrUrl trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the template instance in your **[`Template.myTemplate.onCreated`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated)**, **[`Template.myTemplate.onRendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered)** and **[`Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onDestroyed)** function with `this`.

If you want to access the data context, you can use **[`this.data`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_data)**:

```
Template.profile.onRendered(function() {
    $('#qrblock').qrcode({
        text: this.data.qrUrl
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issues in the future:

There was a much simpler more dynamic way of achieving what I wanted here by simply checking the url for the page and making that the qr code text.  This eliminates the need for qrUrl to be stored for each user and means you don't have to have different versions for both the test site and the deployed site.

Code here:

```
Template.profile.onRendered(function () {
  console.log(this.data.qrUrl);
  var url = window.location.href;
  $('#qrblock').qrcode({text: url});
});
```